# remove element from list of strings?

Tags: java

AH! I have a list of strings... and i just want to remove an element from the list if it is ""

but i keep causing the program to crash. How do i get around this? I made a list of arrays into a List of strings thinking i could remove it that way. Here is what i have:

```
        List<String>list;

        String[] f= new String[file.length()];
        f= file.split("<"); 

        list= Arrays.asList(f); 

        final Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) 
        {
            final String temp = iter.next();
            // TODO check for zero-length arrays
            if (temp.equals("")) 
            {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
        at utilities.Validation.Validate(Validation.java:44)
```

After i convert it to a List, i can print the list just fine.. it's removing elements from it that becomes an problem...

Comment: How is it crashing? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Why are you using the `final` keyword? Have you tried removing them?

Comment: @Jeffrey sorry, forgot to add it, added it now

Comment: @ Bernard, it doesn't make a difference if it's there or not in terms of the exception

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `List` returned by [`Arrays#asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) has a fixed size. Since `remove`ing an element would modify the length, it is unsupported. If you want a `List` that allows removal of items, use `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you were getting the exception has already been answered, but I add a little note about your code: You can remove all empty strings from a list in a much simpler way using the `removeAll()` method. You don't even have to check if the given array is empty, because this method can handle them.

```
String[] array = { "aa", "", "cc", "", "d" };
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));

list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
System.out.println(list);
```

Which prints:

```
[aa, cc, d]
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.asList produces a list that doesn't allow adding or removing elements.

If there is a lot elements to remove then here is a quick way to do that:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String next : file) {
   if (next != null && next.length() != 0) result.add(next);
}
```

Comment: The `List` returned from `Arrays#asList` *is* modifiable. You are allowed to `set` items.

Comment: I meant you cannot remove or add elements (in context of the question). I.e. the structure is not modifiable, while elements, yes, are.